# I would like to know where can I find the azureus2.jar file

Tags: bittorrent

I'm trying to find this file of Vuze (known as Azureus) but seems not to be present.
(Vuze works, but I wish know where this file is). 
I've already tried to search for it with search on local disk, but unsuccesfully.

Answer (score 2):

It is here:

```
/usr/share/java/Azureus2.jar
```

found with

```
dpkg -L azureus | grep jar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
locate -i azureus2.jar
```

That will show you the location of the file. If it doesn't, then you probably need to update the database. You do this by running `sudo updatedb`. Then run the `locate` command again. The `-i` makes the search not be case sensitive.